# PostgreSQL - how to order by a repeating set of same field values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure how to call what I'm aiming to achieve, so it is difficult to find an answer on SO. So I decided to post my own and, hopefully, someone will give it the proper naming.

I have the following values on table `foo`:

```
id       | myvalue
-------------------
98ff5ab  | 501
fa69ac0  | 502
66afb6a  | 501
988af2b  | 503
12a3f4b  | 503
81cde8a  | 502
788bf2b  | 502
55b3f4b  | 503
90ade8a  | 502
```

What I aim to achieve is some sort of `ORDER BY` where I will get `myvalue` repeating like:

```
id       | myvalue
-------------------
98ff5ab  | 501
fa69ac0  | 502
988af2b  | 503
66afb6a  | 501
81cde8a  | 502
12a3f4b  | 503
788bf2b  | 502
55b3f4b  | 503
90ade8a  | 502
```

So I have the field `myvalue` ordered as a sequential group, repeating like `501,502,503; 501,502,503; 502,503; 502`.

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Please see my answer below.  Assume your starting table name is '#temp'

Comment: Thanks, @DanielMarcus! Do you know the name of what I wanted? Just so I can edit the title and help someone that Googled it.

Comment: Basically you are trying to partition the data on 'myvalue' - not sure how else you'd describe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery is not needed:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by myvalue order by null), myvalue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by ordering on the ROW_NUMBER, giving each `myValue` a position in its own group:

```
CREATE TABLE o (
  id serial,
  v int
);

INSERT INTO o(v) VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3);
```

---

```
SELECT id, v, r -- you probably don't want to SELECT r here, simply here to show its value
FROM (
  SELECT id, v, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v) r
  FROM o
) s
ORDER BY r, v
;
┌────┬───┬───┐
│ id │ v │ r │
├────┼───┼───┤
│  1 │ 1 │ 1 │
│  4 │ 2 │ 1 │
│  7 │ 3 │ 1 │
│  2 │ 1 │ 2 │
│  5 │ 2 │ 2 │
│  8 │ 3 │ 2 │
│  3 │ 1 │ 3 │
│  6 │ 2 │ 3 │
│  9 │ 3 │ 3 │
└────┴───┴───┘
(9 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
select id, myvalue from (
select *, row_number() over(partition by myvalue order by myvalue) [order] from #temp )a
order by [order], myvalue
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to sort the result :

```
select id, myvalue 
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by myvalue order by myvalue) seq
      from table t
     ) t
order by seq, myvalue;
```